# Executing scripts on remote server as user

Tags: django, shell, authentication, server, su

I have a django service that is running under sudo account. All the operations like job submission, database operations etc. are performed by sudo account. However there are certain scripts that should be executed as user for traceability purpose later on. What is the best way to transfer the user password so that it can be taken as input to a script that does **su myid** and subsequent commands in the script are run under userid.

For example my server is running as sys_admin. The password *mypassword* should be given by the user from the webpage and passed onto the script as argument.
Below is my sample script:

```
su - myid <<! >/dev/null 2>&1
mypassword
whoami > /dev/tty
!
```

The above script will print **myid** and not sys_admin. What is the best and the most secure way to perform this operation so that password is not exposed to backend as well.

Can some form of encryption and decryption be performed on client or server side with some passphrase?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your are directly passing user input through a sudo shell, this is VERY unsafe if you are, as this can lead to OS command injection

I'm sorry I couldn't directly assist you but if I'm right in how I took that it isnt a great idea to continue the current way it's being done

Maybe someone can offer a safer way of handling it? I'm not experienced in django

Comment: Yeah some secure way is expected to implement this functionality. It does not have to do anything with django.